# Need Help Building SQL Query on dynamic segmentation based on position and dates

Tags: sql

## **Help building single sql query for 3 scenarios described below:**

**Scenario 1: Partial Overlap at the beginning of the segment**
**Input**

| Group_Name | Begin_Position | End_Position | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 5 | 2016 |
| A | 0 | 3 | 2021 |
| B | 0 | 10 | 2016 |

Here I have to do segmentation based on the group and pick begin, end associated with latest date.

For example, in the above case, answer would be:

**Output**

A would be segmented from 0 to 3, 3 to 5. B would be segmented from 0 to 10.

| Group_Name | Begin_Position | End_Position | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 3 | 2021 |
| A | 3 | 5 | 2016 |
| B | 0 | 10 | 2016 |

**Scenario 2: Partial Overlap at the end**

There could be other scenarios such as below:

**Input**

| Group_Name | Begin_Position | End_Position | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 3 | 2021 |
| A | 2 | 5 | 2022 |
| A | 7 | 10 | 2016 |
| B | 0 | 10 | 2016 |

Here, A would be segmented from 0 to 2, 2 to 5, and  7 to 10. And we would have to pick the latest date, associated with each segment.

**Output**

| Group_Name | Begin_Position | End_Position | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2 | 2021 |
| A | 2 | 5 | 2022 |
| A | 7 | 10 | 2016 |
| B | 0 | 10 | 2016 |

**Scenario 3: Complete Overlap**

We could also have a scenario, where older segment, completely overlay another segment.

**Input:**

| Group_Name | Begin_Position | End_Position | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 3 | 2021 |
| A | 0 | 5 | 2022 |
| B | 0 | 10 | 2016 |

**Output:**

| Group_Name | Begin_Position | End_Position | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 5 | 2022 |
| B | 0 | 10 | 2016 |

Thank YOU :)

I have tried using lag functionality but this only works to see the segment next one but does not help if there are more than two segments overlapping.

It would be good, if we can create list, which could store all Begin_Position and End_Position then we can sort the list to create segmentation. Once segmentation per group is completed, one can find the latest date for each segment.